# Why does py.test give this error?

Tags: python, mozilla, pytest

I have installed all the required things, including pytest , still i get "EBUSY: [Resource Device]...." error as show in the image. Why is that? 
I have specified the path too, which by the way doesn't have any special access permissions, so no problem regarding that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) `EBUSY` means "device of resource busy", but [the docs say it isn't actually used in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5814770t.aspx). In windows, [error code 16 actually means "cannot delete current directory"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx). You can see the actual `NTSTATUS` and file operation log that may give a better hint with Process Monitor.

2) The path looks suspicious considering `--driver=firefox`. You do have Selenium with a FirefoxDriver installed and have [set up pytest to use it](http://blogs.gnome.org/danni/2012/11/15/combining-py-test-and-selenium-to-test-webapps/), right?